# How dynamically inject data with dagger?

Tags: android, viewmodel, dagger-2

I have SetupActivity and there in it’s viewModel I fetch data and then that data I need to pass it to MainActivity and it’s Fragment’s ViewModels , I am wondering instead of passing it is it  possible to inject dynamically that settingsData in ViewModel's constructor's

```
settingsViewModel.settingsMutableData.observe(this, Observer {settingsData->
startActivity(MainActivity.getStartInent(this,settingsData))
})
```

````
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(PageViewModel::class)
abstract fun bindHomeViewModel(pageViewModel: PageViewModel): ViewModel```

Here is one of my ViewModel

```class PageViewModel @Inject constructor( homeRepository: HomeRepository) : ViewModel(), Injectable {
}```
````

Comment: Your constructor for your viewModel is empty, so there would not be anything to inject. View models are instantiated using View Model Factories. Basically you need to have a VeiwModelFactory that has your dependencies injected and you can use that to create your view models. What does your view model factory look like? I recommend reading an article like this: https://proandroiddev.com/viewmodel-with-dagger2-architecture-components-2e06f06c9455

Comment: I have updated my question I know how to inject data in constructor of ViewModel.
 but I don't know how to inject dynamically settingsData

Comment: So, at a conceptual level what you're describing is the "Model" part of Model, View, View Model. You want to make your view, "SetupActivity", call something on your ViewModel that saves the updated Model to a place that is shared between your "MainActivity" and your "SetupActivity".

Another way is to make your settingsData implement parcelable and then pass that as an extra to your activities start intent.

Comment: Second way is what I am doing now and I don't want to do that but I didn't understand the first way you describe

Comment: In MVVM architecture, if the model needs to be persisted/shared across views there needs to be some sort of sate holder. The state holder can be held in memory, or persisted to disk. It could be simple like having a `SettingsRepository` that you have in your application module. This settings repository would have a `getSettings()` and `setSettings()`. Your view models would then have the repository injected, and they would use the repository to hold state. If you need persistence on the disk, I recommend using the Room library.

Comment: I see your point I don't need to save on the disk ,I just need to inject it dynamically it is more dagger thing that I am lacking